# How can I make pip use https to get to packages?

Tags: pip

I am using Python behind a firewall, where certain resources and URLs are blocked, but I can access them with https.

When I try install a package with pip, it complains about a bad MD5 hash, because what it is actually retrieving is the proxy server's denial page.

How can I get pip to use https?

Comment: Pip uses https per default since pip 1.3 - otherwise you could always try the `--proxy` flag.

Comment: Mmmm, then why would I be getting this issue?

Comment: Is it for all or just certain packages you try to install?

Comment: Oh, wait, you pointed me to the problem: pip --version gives me 1.1. I just assumed I have got the right version.

Comment: ^_^ I was just about to ask what version of pip you were running :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, it turns out I am using pip 1.1. As limelights points out in his comment, https is enabled by default since 1.3.